# How to Find Out What Version of Display Driver is Installed

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, display-driver, linux-device-driver

One of my favorite games, "Wolfenstein Enemy Territory", has stopped working lately. It throws a segfault during the initialization phase.

I suspect that the reason is a recent update to the video card driver. The problem started after I updated Ubuntu but I do not remember if there was a driver update in the list.

My question is how can I check this. How can I view the current version of the display driver installed and the date it was last updated?

If I discover that this is indeed the problem, will it be possible to revert the update and stay with the previous version of the driver?

Answer (score 0):

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

look at the image [image: graphis info] . The commands will you give you the complete info .

Comment: Thank you, but it shows information regarding the hardware. I am interested in information regarding the driver.

Comment: driver i915 driver and version 3